# What does "dirty stop out" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

In the UK I have recently seen written on the back of a bus (as an advert for the night bus):

> Be a dirty stop out.

I was wondering what the exact meaning of that is?

I can imagine that a stop out is someone who sleeps outside their home after a night out so maybe it is asking people to be promiscuous and spend at the least part of the night with someone else but I could well be wrong.

Comment: It means exactly what you think it means.

Comment: @KillingTime The promiscuity part just seems slightly unlikely for an advert for a night bus.

Comment: Adverts on buses can sometimes [overstep the mark](https://inews.co.uk/news/naked-attraction-adverts-bus-ads-channel-4-series-removed-complaints-1175944)

Comment: It's often used in a less damning, more jocular way, say for someone who's normally back home by 9pm staying in a pub until closing time.

Comment: "dirty" is often used in a mild way; [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dirty) gives the sense "dishonest, dishonorable" and "concerned with sex in a lewd or obscene way", but you'd also get milder uses like "dirty rascal" (found in a common [playground taunt](https://www.historyextra.com/period/stuart/who-king-of-castle-dirty-rascal-rhyme/)), the Christina Aguilera song "Dirrty", and things like "dirty play" (unduly violent but not necessarily illegal tackles in sports like football).

Comment: The 'dirty' part implies they stop over at someone else's place. Now they can get a bus home before breakfast: before their absence is noticed.

Comment: "I was wondering ...". So you are no longer wondering?

Comment: @Anton ?? I guess that's true for everyone who is happy with an answer here

Comment: I wish someone would spell it out CLEARLY, and explain how this fits with the marketing.

Comment: @aparente001: The idea is you can stay out as late as you like, secure in the knowledge that *whatever* time you finally decide to go home, you'll be able to catch an "all-night" bus. Or maybe if you're a ***really dirty*** stop-out (who went off and had sex with some guy/girl you met in the pub last night) you can catch the bus to avoid the proverbial "walk of shame" (walking home next morning in what are obviously the same clothes you wore when you were "out on the town" the night before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED:

> **stop-out**  n.  (a) *colloquial* **one who stays out late**;
>
> 1906   E. Dyson Fact'ry 'Ands ii. 24   *‘See,’ cried Annie—‘See, you dirty stop-out!’ She placed the hat on the floor and danced wildly amongst the feathers.*
>
> 1966   F. Shaw et al. Lern Yerself Scouse 27   *Yer a derty stopout,* [you are a dirty stop-out] *you are a nocturnal reveller*.

In BE, "**dirty** stop-out" rarely had any sexual or moral connotations - "**dirty**" approximates to "bloody/damn, etc., i.e. as an emphatic.

The Teton Bunch: A Western Triobooks. Les Savage · 2017

> “You dirty liar—” Drake had him by the throat again “—you damned dirty liar. You don't have anything. Why should you take ten thousand from me when Binder's willing to lay twenty thousand across the board?”

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the marketing it simply means - Don't go home early, stay out late - ie then you can use the night bus.

Edwin Ashworth is bang on here "It's often used in a less damning, more jocular way, say for someone who's normally back home by 9pm staying in a pub until closing time.

I have seen explanations saying it implies a sexual liaison but that's wide of the mark, IMO, certainly in older usage. In my experience it is/was used facetiously/semi-ironically.

Say you went for a beer after work with colleagues one evening - the next morning:

"Did you stay long after after we left?
"I stayed for a couple more and left about 10"
"Eee you dirty stop-out"

Sort of similar to calling someone "crazy-horse" after they've described a mild evening out.

British work-places have a whole load of such stock phrases, the repetetive/ritual/cliched use of which sort of adds to the humour on another level to the phrase itself.

Comment: Certainly in my family the usage has been along the lines of "I didn't get home till ten last night" "Oo you dirty stop-out!" Nothing sexual or immoral implied.